# Populating Java List in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I am populating a list in backend in java. Setting attribute in spring model and want to iterate and show that list in front end. 
But the list turns out to be empty. I debugged and checked that list is getting populated at the backend. 
Can we anyone help to debug and tell what I am missing. 
In the model I am setting the values to `model.addAttribute("videos", temp);`

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <col width = 33%>
  <col width = 33%>
  <col width = 33%>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center">Title</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">Source</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody> 
      <c:forEach items="${videos}" var="temp">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${temp.title}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${temp.source}"/></td>  
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

[Browser Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgMQn.png)

Controller Code:

```
UserLoginJDBCTemplate uLoginJDBCTemplate = 
         (UserLoginJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("userLoginJDBCTemplate");


      List<VideoList> videos = uLoginJDBCTemplate.listVideos(user.getName(),true);


     // model.addAttribute("modules", modules);
      model.addAttribute("videos", videos);
      return "result";
```

JDBC Connection -

```
List <VideoList> videos = new ArrayList<VideoList>();// jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new VideoListMapper());
          Connection conn = null;

          try {

                conn = dataSource.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
                ps.setString(1, uname);
              ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
              VideoList temp;
              rs =  ps.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    temp = new VideoList(rs.getString("title"),rs.getString("source"),rs.getString("actual_url"));
                    videos.add(temp);
                }
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
                return videos;

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {}
                }
            }
```

Comment: please also post your controller code.

Comment: Contoller makes a call to database and populates this list - 
`List<VideoList> videos = uLoginJDBCTemplate.listVideos(user.getName(),true);`

Class VideoList is as below - 
`public class VideoList {
 private int vlId;
 private String title;
 private String source;
 private String url;
 //Constructor and getters/setters to follow
}`

Comment: you should be setting your model attribute like so `model.addAttribute("videos", videos );` because variable `videos` is holding all the list of `VideoList`.

Comment: I do `model.addAttribute("videos", videos );` only. Was just trying out different names while debugging.
Anyway tried model.addAttribute("videos", videos ); again. Didn't work.

Comment: Though I am sure it wouldn't be the case but - Could it be some bootstrap issues? 
I am also integrating some bootstrap elements.

Comment: Only if by any means your bootstrap is hiding your table datas. You can right click on the page and click inspect to search for your data however.

Comment: Yeah!
I tried that earlier. No luck!
Any other leads?

Comment: You can just cross check and see if the classes are from the right spring package. Check for `Model` and other spring classes.

Comment: I just posted an image in my original post. I am able to get the object reference to the front end (verified using inspect element) but don't know how to move further from it. Still the list shows empty values.

Comment: Also, on the same page I am able to populate other attributes (like username etc. which are not list type) from the same controller.

Comment: Try moving your `c:foreach` out from the table and use some simple html tag first.

Comment: Can you please post your controller code ?

Comment: Just edited the post and added it there.

Comment: Even tried this -
`List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
      temp.add("one");
      temp.add("two");
      model.addAttribute("videos", temp);`
@SaranyaSubramanian @AbdullahKhan

Comment: Can you show your method definition of your controller method? I want the return type. You should return the modelView object right ? @WaltWhitman

Comment: Never mind. I was able to figure it out. 
It was related to placement of jstl jar.
Thanks a ton!